# Spring3 MappingJacksonJsonView vs. MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

Spring 3 includes the ContentnegotiatingViewResolver which can be used to decide on the views based on Aceept HTTP header for example.

This would be one way to render a json view, another way (which also provides mapping for incoming request bodies to objects) would be to setup the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.

Which one is used best? Are there any guidelines or hints?

Thanx!

Comment: accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Adding a few details to my question. I'd like to support both XML and JSON, plus being able to reduce rendered views (detail/summary view) is a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter looks alike a good approach , in case you want to skip the view resolution altogether.

HttpMessageConverter would allow you to do do more like XML,etcImages,etc easily and you can also unit test them :)